# How to make a type that for all intents and purposes act like a string, since I cannot inherit from a string

Tags: c#, string, .net-core

I like types. 
Like to be able to specify meaning to a string or int etc)

A string or an int can be almost anything,

I enjoy giving a string a meaningful type. 
I also prefer that when you have a longish function call. That way people who use it
wont pass in strings in the wrong order.

I often use strings as parameters and I want "MembersName" as a Type derived from string.

I can easily do something like MembersName.Value where string is a property of another class.
I would rather derive my class from String but that is not possible since it is sealed.

I have looked at the System.String source and thought about taking it out use it to make my own String type, but I decided against it.

Then I started creating my own stand in base class that I could derive my other string-like types from StringBase (realy good name).

I am working on implementing
IEquatable, ICloneable, IComparable, IComparable, IConvertible, IEquatable, IEnumerable

In the base type to make it appear as much like a string as possible.

I would prefer to be able to Membername == "Phil Collins".

It is also desirable to mimick other features of String.

Is this the right path? and does anyone have a version of it written already?
I figure the need must have come up before from someone else?
I tried hunting Google and GitHub without much luck so far.

Am I going down the right path? 
Or is what I am trying to do nearly impossible?

Comment: I don't like implicit casting, but maybe in this case you should just implement implicit casting of you type to string and vise versa?

Comment: I don't understand the "why". If you want to restrict the possible values it sounds like an enum but if all values are possible, then it's a string. I can't see any reason to create a derived class that represents a string without any additional functionality. The "what's inside" is described by the member name... Or is there something I don't see?

Comment: "I enjoy giving a string a meaningful type. I also prefer that when you have a longish function call. That way people who use it wont pass in strings in the wrong order." You seem to be describing an _enum_... Are you sure you don't want an enum instead?

Comment: @ChristophLütjen yes, it has its uses, in functional languages its a feature used extensively because they typically provide lightweight type wrappers that allow you to sematically distiguish in your code what essentially is the same type. Example: ints that represent numbers or bit masks that are passed into a function. A way to ensure you dont mix them up, and its possible if you have a lot of functions that differ slightly in how the arguments are passed, is creating these lightweight wrappers. Once you do it, its not possible to pass a bitmask where a number is expected or vice-versa.

Comment: Alas c# doesn't have this feature of easily creating lightweight type wrappers... yet.

Comment: @InBetween - ... for ints vs bitmasks,etc... that makes a lot of sense. But when talking about strings?

Comment: @ChristophLütjen The principle is the same. A string can mean a lot of different things: a regular string, an encoded number, a key, an email, etc. Yes you can mitigate all this with good naming conventions but its still a handy thing to have if its easily available. Ocaml for instance provides it for free (its essentially a one liner). If creating these light weight wrappers is a hassle, like it is nowdays in c#, then its obviously not worth it.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen A good explanation why its useful is this wonderful but, alas, unfinished [Eric Lippert sieries on Zork](https://ericlippert.com/2016/02/01/west-of-house/). I think the relevant part to this discussion is in the third episode.

Comment: For those that doesn't understand the purpose of it, it would be like a monad, an amplified string, you could think of a type for FirstName, it's actually just a string, but it cannot be confused with a LastName type, which is also a string, nor can you pass it to a method that requires a SocialSecurityNumber, which is also a string (of digits). It might be just an ordinary string, but it is a *typed* string.

Comment: I think the main issue here is that if you stop thinking of it as a string, and start to think of it as a "First Name", you might consider that you don't actually need to have all the behavior available that a string has. For instance, why would you need a Substring on a First Name? Perhaps Initials would be what you need it for? In essence, it might be that you don't require a full string but need to better consider what operations you actually need, and only implement those.

Comment: In my opinion, the best way to implement this right now is to create some basic base types that implement the brunt of the required features, and then minimalize the features you build into it, and then make it easy to convert it to and from strings. That way, you can get a FirstName (or whatever type you need) quite easily, but easily convert it to a string when you need to get the full string features available. **However**, it will not be ideal, but then again you can't *get* that, because the support is just not there.

Answer (score 3):

I think this can be a good design as it provides type safety for different types of strings (enabling better support for overloading methods, refactoring etc.).

I dug up something from an old project that might get you started at least.

In this case I had a strongly typed `UserId` functioning (almost) as a string.

Maybe if you complete this with implicit operators as 'GuruStron' suggested you will have something to work on, although if I remember correctly I chose not to provide implicit operators as it made the type "less type safe".

```
public struct UserId : IStringIdentifier, IEquatable<UserId>
{
    public UserId(string id) : this() => Value = id;

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public static bool operator ==(UserId id1, UserId id2) 
        => id1.Value == id2.Value;

    public static bool operator !=(UserId id1, UserId id2) 
        => id1.Value != id2.Value;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is UserId other)
            return Equals(other);

        return false;
    }

    public bool Equals(UserId other) => Value.Equals(other.Value);
    public override string ToString() => Value;
    public override int GetHashCode() => Value.GetHashCode();
}
```

**Edit:** Cleaned it up a bit.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that look at all the boiler plate code needed... if you need 10 or 20 or more of these wrappers, this is not the way to go.

Comment: @InBetween The problem is that you don't have any alternatives. You could *generate* this code, but it would still be there. Though I feel some of it could be handled by a generic base class, but not if you want to use value types.

Comment: @LasseVKarlsen yes I know. It’s very useful but I’m not sure it’s worth the hassle in c#. The language doesn’t support these lightweight wrappers like many functional languages do.